# React-native-chart-kit erro ao mudar o objeto data

Tags: react-native

Estou usando a biblioteca react-native-chart-kit para renderizar alguns gráficos no meu app.
A estrutura básica do meu código é a seguinte;

```js
<LineChart
   data={data}
   width={Dimensions.get("window").width}
   height={220}
   chartConfig={{
       backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
       useShadowColorFromDataset: true,
       propsForBackgroundLines: {
            strokeWidth:"1",
            stroke: "#dcdcdc",
            strokeDasharray:"0" 
       },
       backgroundGradientFrom: "#ffffff",
       backgroundGradientTo: "#ffffff",
       decimalPlaces: 0,
       paddingRight: 0,
       paddingTop: 0,
       color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0,0,0,0)`,
       labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
   }}
   style={{
       marginLeft: -(((Dimensions.get("window").width -60) * 10) / 100)
   }} 
   bezier
/>
```

O atributo data é onde vai o objeto com os dados do gráfico, inicio ele com null porém ele nesse momento ainda não foi renderizado na tela, pois eu tenho uma condição em que caso Data seja igual a null ele não é renderizado, após pegar as informações no back-end e construir um objeto para setar o novo Data, ao setar esse novo valor o react-native-chart-kit me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined
This error is located at:
```

Eu acredito que esteja faltando o atributo `decorator` porém eu não achei nada relacionado a esse atributo e como usa-lo.

Componente pai.

```
mport React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import MainStyle from '../content/css/Main.styles';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import ChartMenuAcessoComponent from './Utils/components/Chart-menu-acesso/Chart-menu-acesso.component';
import Api from '../Api';

const sizePercent = (size=Number(0), percent) => {
    return (percent * size ) / 100;
}

//esse é um exemplo de como é o objeto data
// {
//     labels: ["Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sab"],
//     datasets: [
//         { 
//             data: [ 8,6,4,2,0,10 ], 
//             color: (opacity = 1) => "#7bedeb", 
//         },
//         {
//             data: [10,13,15,20,56,3],
//             color: (opacity = 1) => "#00bab3",
//         }
//     ]
// }



export default props => {
    

    const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState(null);
    const [tempInfos, setTempInfos] = useState(null);
    const [dadosChart, setDadosChart] = useState(null);

    const coletInfos = async () => {
        setUserInfos(JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("__Verifica_usuario")));
        setTempInfos(JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("__Verifica_Temp_Acesso")));
    }

    const generateName = () => {
        return  (
            <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextBold,style.textUser]}>{userInfos.nome.split(' ').length > 1 ? `${userInfos.nome.split(' ')[0][0]}${userInfos.nome.split(' ')[1][0]}` : userInfos.nome[0]}</Text>
        )
    }

    const getDadosChart = async () => {
        let response = await Api.getAndPostRequestJSON('v1/relatorio/acessos-ultimos-dias', null, "GET");
        if(response.eu && response.outros){
            let data = {
                labels: generateLabels(response.eu),
                datasets: generateDatasets(response.eu, response.outros)
            };
            setDadosChart(data);
        }
    }

    const generateLabels = labels => {
        let l = [];
        
        labels.forEach((v) => {
            l.push(String(v.periodo));
        });
       
        return l;
    }

    const generateDatasets = (e,o) => {
        let eu = {
            data: [],
            color:  (opacity = 1) => "#7bedeb",
        }

        let outros = {
            data: [],
            color:  (opacity = 1) => "#00bab3"
        }

        e.forEach( _ => {
            eu.data.push(_.quantidade);
        });

        o.forEach(_ => {
            outros.data.push(_.quantidade);
        });

        return [eu,outros]
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        coletInfos();
        getDadosChart();
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={MainStyle.__Container}>
            <ScrollView style={MainStyle.__Container}>
                
                <View style={style.flexView}>
                    <View style={style.viewIcon}>
                        <Icon name="notifications" size={30} color="#8daac8" />
                    </View>
                    <View style={style.viewContentFlexView}>
                        
                        <View style={style.userBox}>
                            {userInfos == null ? false : generateName()}
                        </View>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={style.buttonSeta}>
                            <Icon name="chevron-down" size={30} color="#b4c2d5" />
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <View style={style.flexInfosUser}>
                            <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextNormal, style.textInfoDefault]}>{tempInfos !==  null ? tempInfos.empresa.nome_fantasia : false}</Text>
                            <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextBold, style.textInfoDefault, {fontSize: RFValue(17)}]}>{userInfos !== null ? userInfos.nome.split(" ")[0] : false}</Text>
                            <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextNormal, style.textInfoDefault]}>{userInfos !== null ? userInfos.papel_empresa : false}</Text>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                </View>
                
                <View style={style.separator}/>

                <View style={style.viewFlexCriarConteudo}>
                    <View style={style.viewFlexTitle}>
                        <Icon name="star" size={30} color="#b4c2d5"/>
                        <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextBold, style.textTitle]}>Atalho</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={style.viewButtonCriarConteudo}>
                        <View style={style.buttonView}>
                            <LinearGradient start={{x: 0, y: 0}} end={{x: 1, y: 0}} colors={['#00B2FE', '#00E294']} style={[MainStyle.__GradienteFlex, {borderRadius: 5}]}>
                                <View style={style.flexFullView}>
                                    <TouchableHighlight style={style.buttonConteudo}>
                                        <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextNormal, style.textButton]}>Criar conteúdo</Text>
                                    </TouchableHighlight>
                                    <TouchableHighlight style={style.buttonConteudoOption}>
                                        <Icon name="caret-down"  size={15} color="#ffffff" />
                                    </TouchableHighlight>
                                </View>
                            </LinearGradient>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={style.separator}/>

                <View style={style.viewFlexChart}>
                    <View style={style.viewFlexTitle}>
                        <Icon name="shield-checkmark" size={30} color="#b4c2d5"/>
                        <Text style={[MainStyle.__TextBold, style.textTitle]}>Acessos à plataforma</Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={style.viewChartFlex}>
                        {dadosChart == null ? false : (
                            <ChartMenuAcessoComponent props={props} dadosChart={dadosChart} />
                        )

                        }
                    </View>
                    
                </View>
            
            </ScrollView>                
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}


const style = StyleSheet.create({
    flexView: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 130,
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between"
    },
    viewIcon: {
        flex: .4,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    viewContentFlexView: {
        flex: 2,
        display: 'flex',
        position: 'relative',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },

    userBox: {
        width: sizePercent((Dimensions.get("window").width - 60) - 100, 25),
        height: sizePercent((Dimensions.get("window").width - 60) - 100, 25),
        borderRadius: sizePercent((Dimensions.get("window").width - 60) - 100, 30) / 2,
        backgroundColor: "#d5e6fa",
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    textUser: {
        color: '#2C7BE5',
        fontSize: RFValue(22),
    },

    buttonSeta: {
        width: 30,
        height: 30,
        marginLeft: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    textInfoDefault: {
        color: '#97a9c6',
        fontSize: RFValue(15),
    },

    flexInfosUser: {
        flex: 1,
        height: "100%",
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        marginLeft: 15
    },

    separator: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 2,
        backgroundColor: "#eff2f6",
    },

    viewFlexCriarConteudo: {
        width: "100%",
        marginTop: 5,
        height: 130,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    viewFlexTitle: {
        width: "100%",
        height: 30,
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: 'center',

    },

    textTitle: {
        color: '#97a9c6',
        fontSize: RFValue(20),
        marginLeft: 10,
    },

    viewButtonCriarConteudo: {
        width:"100%",
        height: 70,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    buttonView: {
        width: '50%',
        height: 41,
    },

    flexFullView: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    
    buttonConteudo: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 41,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    buttonConteudoOption: {
        flex: .3,
        borderLeftColor: "#dbdbdb", //#01d69f
        borderLeftWidth: 1,
        height: 41,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },

    textButton: {
        color: "#ffffff",
        fontSize: RFValue(16)
    },

    viewFlexChart: {
        width: "100%",
        marginTop: 20,
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    viewChartFlex: {
        width: "100%",
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 20,
    }
});
```

Esse é o component filho.

```
import React, {useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text,Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { RFValue } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import MainStyles from '../../../../content/css/Main.styles';
import { LineChart } from "react-native-chart-kit";


export default (props, dadosChart) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState({
        labels: [""],
        datasets: [
            {data: [0], color: (opacity) => "#00bab3"}
        ],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
    
        setData(dadosChart);
    }, []);


    return (
        <View style={style.fullContainer}>
            <View style={style.headerChart}>
                <View style={style.labelView}>
                    <View  style={[style.circleBox, {backgroundColor: "#00bab3"}]}/>
                    <Text style={[MainStyles.__TextLight, style.textLabel]}>Eu</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={style.labelView}>
                    <View  style={[style.circleBox, {backgroundColor: "#7bedeb"}]}/>
                    <Text style={[MainStyles.__TextLight, style.textLabel]}>Outros</Text>
                </View>
            </View>

            <View style={style.ViewGrafico}>

                <LineChart
                    data={data}
                    width={Dimensions.get("window").width}
                    height={220}
                    chartConfig={{
                        backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
                        useShadowColorFromDataset: true,
                        propsForBackgroundLines: {
                            strokeWidth:"1",
                            stroke: "#dcdcdc",
                            strokeDasharray:"0" 
                        },
                        backgroundGradientFrom: "#ffffff",
                        backgroundGradientTo: "#ffffff",
                        decimalPlaces: 0,
                        paddingRight: 0,
                        paddingTop: 0,

                        color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0,0,0,0)`,
                        labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${opacity})`,
                    }}

                    style={{
                        marginLeft: -(((Dimensions.get("window").width -60) * 10) / 100)
                    }} 
                    bezier
                 />
            </View>


        </View>
    )
}


const style = StyleSheet.create({

    fullContainer: {
        width: '100%',
    },

    headerChart: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 30,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },

    labelView: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 15,
    },

    circleBox: {
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginRight: 10
    },

    textLabel: {
        fontSize: RFValue(17),
        color: "#4e5a6b"
    },

    ViewGrafico: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 15,
    }
});
```

Reprodução do erro [erro](https://snack.expo.io/q6hYwZJWu)

Comment: Editei a pergunta, coloquei os components que estão envolvidos nesse erro!

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@rafatcb/react-native-chart-kit-sopt), tentei reproduzir o problema mas não consegui. Tenta criar um [mcve] em um Snack.

Comment: Bom dia, editei o código lá no expo reproduzindo o problema. [erro](https://snack.expo.io/q6hYwZJWu)

Comment: No arquivo `Chart.js` escreva `export default ({props, dadosChart})`, entre `{}`. Esse é o problema... Você está passando a props `props` e `dadosChart`, tudo chega dentro de um único objeto no seu componente.

Comment: Nossa cara kkkk que erro mais bobo, eu estava tão vidrado no decorator que nem reparei isso kkkkk Obrigado!